# OpenJPA Configuration in WAS 7.0.0.25

Tags: java, performance, jpa, websphere, openjpa

I am looking at the performance optimization of Open JPA for my WAS 7.0.0.25 server. I enabled OpenJPA trace from WAS console to understand what properties are taken for caching.

There is no openjpa.=  type entry in my persistance.xml. But I can see entries in the trace.log as below:

```
openjpa.IgnoreChanges: false
openjpa.FlushBeforeQueries: 0
openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode: 0
```

But i could not find the configuration that sets these properties so that I can play around with them.

Can anyone guide me where I can find these values coming from the Open JPA provided by WAS 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to the documentation you should add this line to your **persistence.xml**:

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
```

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/ref_guide_logging_openjpa.html

---

**ADDED**

If you add those keys in your persistence.xml, probably the default values will be overridden.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="...">

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="oracle" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.AutoDetach" value="close" />
            <property name="openjpa.DetachState" value="loaded" />
            <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false" />
            <property name="openjpa.Optimistic" value="true" />
            <property name="openjpa.Multithreaded" value="true" />
            <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
            <property name="openjpa.RestoreState" value="all" />
            <property name="openjpa.ManagedRuntime" value="auto" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

Comment: Thanks edubriguenti. But I need to modify some properties. Where can I do that for the default OpenJPA provided by WAS?

Comment: FYI -- I would never recommend setting the openjpa.Multithreaded to true. That feature is buggy (at best) and can cause deadlocks.

Comment: Tks for the advice @Rick.

Answer (score 0):

Xhings -

If you are looking for default configuration values, you should start by looking at the [user manual](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/). That beings said, the only property that I would recommend (from a performance point of view) to change is `openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode`. Setting that property to `always` has shown some performance impact.

Comment: Thanks Rick. The issue I am concerned is heavy memory foot print of Open JPA in HeapDumps. Nearly 60% of the heap is utilized due to persistance. I want to check if persistance is managed properly through OpenJPA configuration and from the code. Please advice if you have any inputs regarding heavy memory foot print.

Comment: Just to add to the above point, this heap usage goes to 90% due to openJPA and although there is no OOM heap dumps created, the application and the server becomes unresponsive during load testing. We have 2 Gigs (Min = Max) assigned to the JVM that extensivly uses Open JPA also we have increased our swap space to 4 gigs for 12 Gig of RAM.

Comment: I would suggest to take thread/heap dumps and look at what is going on rather than blindly setting properties.